# Custom Javascript GTM variable - remove UTMs

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I've got a CSJ variable to capture the last parameter of the URL. Given I'm interested on capturing the location and its position may vary (see example below), I managed to create a custom variable that will always give me the last parameter in the URL.

URL examples:
https://www.example.co.nz/location/**holmwood**

https://www.example.co.nz/find-a-location/auckland/**central-auckland**

The issue I'm having is that my script (see below) is not only capturing the last parameter of the URL, but any string after the "?" symbol, which are mainly UTMs.

**Code:**

```
function(){
  var pageUrl = window.location.href;
  return pageUrl.split("/")[pageUrl.split("/").length - 1];
}
```

So, on my GA view instead of seeing the ph + the location, I see a large string:

[image]

I know I could use page path and remove query from there, but for a specific event I'd rather sort that out from the custom variable because of the type of value I'm passing.

What else should I add to my script to keep it completely the same and exclude any query parameters that might be automatically tagged?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than returning the first split, I would then put it through an additional one where you are splitting on the '?'

```
function(){
var pageUrl = window.location.href;
var lastSlash = pageUrl.split("/")[pageUrl.split("/").length - 1];
return lastSlash.split("?",1);
}
```

Comment: Great, Seems to be working. It's coming as an array so into square brackets. Do you know if those [] will show up on the GA views?

Thanks.

Comment: My first thought would be no, the brackets won’t show but I am not 100% sure.